# Paypal - encrypt buynow dynamic checkout button with php

Tags: php, paypal, localhost, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have spent the last week trying to make an encrypted 'checkout with paypal' button.

finally i found Encrypted web payments with php in this website "https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/502"

i m trying to implement in that example according to my site in the localhost .but show an error"Received error #3"

this is my code 
Example.php

```
         <?php
         $config = array("cert_id" => "PHCVJS6GDV6TY", "business" => "roki_1347003608_biz@gmail.com","basedir" => "./",
          "certstore" => "./", "tempdir" => "./", "my_private" => "my-prvkey.pem",          "my_public" => "my.pubcert.pem",
         "paypal_public" => "paypal_cert_pem.txt");
          $paypal = new PayPal_EncryptedButtons($config);

      // You can add parameters to the button one by one (name, value) or you can pass two
       // arrays of names and values, as documented below.
    $names = array("amount", "currency_code", "item_name", "item_number");
        $values = array("2.56", "USD", "Dave's secret encryption sauce (encryption via PHP)", "123456");
     $paypal->addButtonParam($names, $values);

     // We can now generate our code
     $result = $paypal->encryptButtonData();
     if ($result !== PP_ERROR_OK) {
     // Something went wrong
      echo "Received Error #".$result."\n";
       exit;
         }

   // Get the string of encrypted button data

           echo '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"       method="post">';
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">';
         echo '<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!">';             
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="';
        echo $paypal->getButton();
         echo '">';
        echo "</form>\n";
         ?>
      </body>
         </html>
```

EncryptedButtons.php

```
          <?php

        define("PP_ERROR_OK", 0);
        define("PP_ERROR_FILE", 1);
        define("PP_ERROR_OPENSSL", 2);
        define("PP_ERROR_DATA", 3);
        define("PP_ERROR_PARAMS", 4);
        define("PP_ERROR_NOTFOUND", 5);
        define("PP_ERROR_UNKNOWN", 6);


       require_once "/wamp/www/var/Php/Config.php";


       class PayPal_EncryptedButtons {



        /** Button Data Array */
          var $buttonData = array();

        /** Config Pointer */
          var $config;

           /** Internal Data Handler */
               var $_data;

               /** Random Transaction ID */
            var $_rnd;

                var $debug = true;

          function PayPal_EncryptedButtons($config = array()) {
          $this->config = new PayPal_EncryptedButtons_Config;
               /*
               foreach ($config as $name => $val) {
            if ($this->config->$name) {
          $this->config->$name = $val;
              }
              else {
           return PP_ERROR_UNKNOWN;
             }
          }
              */
             return;
            }


              function changeConfig($name, $value = "") {
           if ($this->config->$name) {
           $this->config->$name = $value;
              return true;
                }
           else {
            return false;
             }
                   }


           function addButtonParam($names = "", $values = "") {
            if ((is_array($names) && !is_array($values)) || (!is_array($names) &&       is_array($values))) {
                  return PP_ERROR_PARAMS;
            }
            elseif (is_array($names) && is_array($values)) {
            if (count($names) !== count($values)) {
             return PP_ERROR_PARAMS;
               }
                $i = 0;
           while ($i < count($names)) {
              $this->buttonData[$names[$i]] = $values[$i];
           $i++;
         }
           return PP_ERROR_OK;
              }
          else {
         if ($names == "" || $values == "") {
        return PP_ERROR_PARAMS;
      }
         else {
         $this->buttonData[$names] = $values;
         return PP_ERROR_OK;
           }
         }
              }


            function delButtonParam($name = "") {
       if ($name == "") {
       return PP_ERROR_PARAMS;
     }
        if ($this->buttonData[$name] !== null) {
          $this->buttonData[$name] = null;
        return PP_ERROR_OK;
        }
           return PP_ERROR_NOTFOUND + 10;
              }


          function encryptButtonData() {
       $this->encryptedButton = null;
            if (!is_dir($this->config->basedir)) {
      if (!mkdir($this->config->basedir)) {
     return PP_ERROR_NOTFOUND + 20;
       }
           }
             @chdir($this->config->basedir);
          $this->_data = "cmd=_xclick\n";
        $this->_data .= "business=".$this->config->business."\n";
            $this->_data .= "receiver_email=".$this->config->receiver_email."\n";
           foreach ($this->buttonData as $name => $val) {
       if ($val == null) { continue; }
        $this->_data .= $name."=".$val."\n";
            }
         $this->_data .= "cert_id=".$this->config->cert_id;
          $this->_rnd = rand(100000, 999999);
       if (!is_dir($this->config->tempdir)) {
        if (!@mkdir($this->config->tempdir)) {
     return PP_ERROR_NOTFOUND + 30;
            }
       }
              $f = @fopen($this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".1", "w");
           //if (!$f) { return PP_ERROR_FILE; }
              if (!$f) { return 41; }
                    fwrite($f, trim($this->_data), strlen(trim($this->_data)));
                fclose($f);
                    if (!file_exists($this->config->my_private)) {
                 return 145;
                     }
                  if (!file_exists($this->config->my_public)) {
                 return 245;
                  }
           if (!file_exists($this->config->paypal_public)) {
       return 345;
           }
            if (!file_exists($this->config->my_private) || !file_exists($this->config->my_public) || !file_exists($this->config->paypal_public)) {
             return PP_ERROR_NOTFOUND + 40;
            }
              $exec = $this->config->openssl." smime -sign -in ".$this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".1 -signer ".$this->config->my_public." -inkey ".$this->config->my_private." -outform der -nodetach -binary > ".$this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".2";
       $status1 = `$exec`;
           $exec = $this->config->openssl." smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem ".$this->config->paypal_public." < ".$this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".2 > ".$this-    >config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".3";
             $status2 = `$exec`;
             $this->encryptedButton = trim(file_get_contents($this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".3"));
             @unlink($this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".1");
           @unlink($this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".2");
            @unlink($this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".3");
            if (strpos($status1, "No such file or directory") !== false ||        strpos($status2, "No such file or directory") !== false) {
           return PP_ERROR_OPENSSL;
         }
          if (!$this->encryptedButton) {
         return PP_ERROR_DATA;
        }
            return PP_ERROR_OK;
       }


           function getButton() {
       if (!$this->encryptedButton) {
      return "";
          }
       return $this->encryptedButton;
        }
```

config.php

```
       <?php
      class PayPal_EncryptedButtons_Config {
      var $cert_id = "PHCVJS6GDV6TY";
       var $business = "roki_1347003608_biz@gmail.com";

       var $receiver_email = "";

        var $basedir = "/wamp/www/var/";

        var $certstore = "/wamp/www/key/cert/";

        var $tempdir = "/wamp/www/temp/";

        var $openssl = "openssl";

       var $my_private = "/wamp/www/key/cert/my-prvkey.pem";

       /* Your Public Certificate Filename */
       var $my_public = "/wamp/www/key/cert/my.pubcert.pem";

       /* PayPal's Public Certificate Filename */
        var $paypal_public = "/wamp/www/key/cert/paypal_cert_pem.txt";

      }

        ?>
```

Error

```
       Received Error #3
```

can anyone know what error is this any one help me how to fix this really i m  help less.thanks

Comment: Are you sure all the directories / paths are correct in your config etc? Especially the tempdir.

Comment: yes i check all the directories are correct

Comment: in the example.php if i remove! this  $result = $paypal->encryptButtonData();
     if ($result == PP_ERROR_OK) {
     // Something went wrong
      echo "Received Error #".$result."\n";
       exit;
         }it goes to paypal page and shows Some required information is missing or incomplete. Please correct your entries and try again.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I have a feeling after testing this that it's something to do with it trying to execute code that it can't do locally (openssl). It's failing to create the file with an extension of .3

Comment: but it write the file in the temp directories.then you know any solution bro

Comment: Have you tried testing it on a production server?

Comment: In fact, it does require OpenSSL to work, please read the documentation that comes with the code.

Comment: nope i want to run this in localhost

Comment: The path needs to point to where openssl is on your system, and by default, most localhost installations will not have openssl as far as I'm aware.

Comment: i put openssl in c:/wamp/www/var/openssl this the my path for openssl .but it showing the same error.is right brother

Comment: Please check my answer for further details.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is for the script to work you need to have OpenSSL. In the comments of the script it does specify it uses it to encrypt the PayPal buttons.

This line is what is causing the issue, as it is unable to create the file as OpenSSL has not be specified.

```
$exec = $this->config->openssl." smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem ".$this->config->paypal_public." < ".$this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".2 > ".$this->config->tempdir.$this->_rnd.".3";
```

You need to specify the path to OpenSSL in order for it to work.

The below is taken from the site you linked.

Config:

```
/* OpenSSL Path - Path to the OpenSSL Binary */
/* If openssl isn't in your PATH, then change this to where it's located, otherwise leave it as it is */
/* No trailing slash */
var $openssl = "openssl";
```

Information on using OpenSSL in your localhost can be found with the following google query:
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=openssl+for+localhost

OpenSSL: http://www.openssl.org/

Hope that helps.

Comment: i follow the link you provided for openssl for localhost.but still it showing the same error

Comment: Are you sure OpenSSL is installed and working correctly? http://www.phpjoel.com/2011/04/07/installing-ssl-using-openssl-on-a-wamp-localhost/ - Attempt to do the "GENERATE KEY" section, if that works, do all the sections after, and including  "MODIFY HTTPD-SSL.CONF"

Comment: ya its generating key correctly. but while setup in localhost do we need to change any thing in router

Comment: No - localhost stays within the machine, it doesn't even get to the router (unless trying to access from outside if that is set up)

Comment: ok brother its not working .now i going to check it in live .i m using debian linux .can u provide any like how to do paypal intergration in linux

Comment: I'm not sure the OS matters, I've used Paypal Standards Pro + IPN, but I've not needed to encrypt buttons so I'm not much help with that.

Comment: it safe without encrypt button in paypai.then what you done for security

Comment: Well what can not encrypting a button allow them to do? Not much, the rest of the details are usually stored within hidden fields, and even then, they'd be able to only change them for themselves, and not others. And thus anyone that changes those fields (with malicious intent) will only affect their purchase, and I doubt they'd do it because of that, as no-one is going to pay money to themselves lol.

Comment: can you know how to integrate paypal in the mvc architectural.in my project i m using mvc architectural.can i get your mail id

Comment: do you know How to pass the user enter amount value to the paypal.can you help me i m really helpless

Answer (score 1):

Setting this up can be a real bear or impossible on some hosting plans. Another suggestion is not to encrypt, but to use a tamper detection hash trick, and then check this when the IPN is processed. I document this here:

[How do I make a PayPal encrypted buy now button with custom fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14489512/105539)